# Elixir: How are default arguments that are not at the end treated?

Tags: elixir

When I run the following Elixir script, it prints out `{"K", "Y", "L"}`.

```
defmodule MyMod do
  def make_tuple(a \\ "X", b \\ "Y", c) do
    {a, b, c}
  end
end

IO.inspect(MyMod.make_tuple("K", "L"))
```

Why doesn't it output `{"X", "K", "L"}`? What is the mechanism behind this behavior?

Answer (score 10):

You are correct: Elixir uses any "excess" arguments provided to override a function's default values for some or all of its parameters, filled from left to right.  My understanding of this came from the Programming Elixir 1.6 book by Dave Thomas.

The trick is that for functions with default arguments, the compiler actually generates *multiple* functions.  A function defined like this:

```
defmodule Example do 
  def func(p1, p2 \\ 2, p3 \\ 3, p4) do 
    IO.inspect [p1, p2, p3, p4]
  end 
end
```

Actually gets compiled down to a module that looks something like this:

```
defmodule Example do 
  def func(p1, p4) do
    func(p1, 2, 3, p4)
  end

  def func(p1, p2, p4) do
    func(p1, p2, 3, p4)
  end

  def func(p1, p2, p3, p4) do 
    IO.inspect [p1, p2, p3, p4]
  end 
end
```

By the way, you can see this by using a module's "magic" `module_info/0` function, e.g. `Example.module_info()`.

Calling your functions with some sample values will help you understand how they are interpreted, and there may be a few surprises.

```
Example.func("a", "b")           # => ["a",2,3,"b"]

Example.func("a", "b", "c")      # => ["a","b",3,"c"]  <--- !!!

Example.func("a", "b", "c", "d") # => ["a","b","c","d"]
```

It may be a bit easier to see this behavior with a function like this:

```
def func(p1 \\ 1, p2 \\ 2) do 
  IO.inspect [p1, p2]
end
```

And calling it with only 1 argument provided.  It will use the provided argument on the left side; the default on the right still gets used:

```
func("a")    #  =>  ["a", 2]
```

I agree that things do get confusing when a function has optional arguments that aren't at the end of the argument list.

Answer (score 4):

Just from experimenting with it a bit, it seems like it assigns the arguments from the left. So in this case:

```
defmodule MyMod do
  def make_tuple(a \\ "X", b, c \\ "Y", d) do
    {a, b, c, d}
  end
end

IO.inspect(MyMod.make_tuple(1, 2, 3))
```

You get `{1, 2, "Y", 3}` - this is a "left-most" interpretation of the arguments provided. This leads to a situation where if you add an argument "at the end" it changes the meaning of the previous arguments, and (I assume) is the reason why people usually avoid having optional arguments that are not at the end of the argument list.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, [Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/693166/pawe%C5%82-obrok) is correct.

To understand why this happens, you should most probably look at what happens when a `def` macro is used. This is not as easy as it seems, since this is one of the [bootsrap functions](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/f3806f82afe833f5c76120b06a0d124829914908/lib/elixir/src/elixir_bootstrap.erl#L13) required to compile elixir, so it is written in erlang.

What we are actually interested in is the function [`unpack_defaults`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/aa78b322912f687fb74db9f1a10f2aec26cb7a3f/lib/elixir/src/elixir_def.erl#L262), that is one of the functions that handles default arguments, here we can notice the lines:

```
unpack_defaults(Kind, Meta, Name, [{'\\\\', DefaultMeta, [Expr, _]} | T] = List, Acc, Clauses) ->
  body...
  unpack_defaults(Kind, Meta, Name, T, [Expr | Acc], [Clause | Clauses]);
unpack_defaults(Kind, Meta, Name, [H | T], Acc, Clauses) ->
  unpack_defaults(Kind, Meta, Name, T, [H | Acc], Clauses);
unpack_defaults(_Kind, _Meta, _Name, [], Acc, Clauses) ->
  {lists:reverse(Acc), lists:reverse(Clauses)}.
```

We don't care about details of how default arguments get sorted, however you can notice that the 4-th argument of every function is the actual list of arguments, then we have `Acc` witch are the resulting arguments and `Clauses` that are the defaults.

Both of them are added to the list using `[Clause | Clauses]` and `[H | Acc]` resulting in a reverse order list, and are reversed as the last return `{lists:reverse(Acc), lists:reverse(Clauses)}.`